# Filter a pandas dataframe based on two columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to filter a pandas dataframe based on two columns, so that for each value in column 1 only those rows are left where column 2 is the minimum. I know it sounds confusing like this, so here is an example:

```
> df = pd.DataFrame([{'a':'anno1', 'ppm':1},{'a':'anno1', 'ppm':2},{'a':'anno2', 'ppm':2},{'a':'anno2', 'ppm':2}])

> df
       a  ppm
0  anno1    1
1  anno1    2
2  anno2    2
3  anno2    2
```

And I want rows 0,2 and 3, because for `anno1`, the minimum `ppm` is `1`, and for `anno2` the minimum `ppm` is `2` (keep both rows!). So I started with a `groupby`:

```
> grouped_series = df.groupby(['a']).ppm.min()
> grouped_series
a
anno1    1
anno2    2
```

Now I have for each value in `a` the minimum `ppm`. But how do I use this series to filter the original dataframe? Or is there even an easier way to do this? I tried several variations of:

```
new_df = df.loc[ df.loc[:,'ppm']==grouped_series.loc[df.loc[:,'a']] , :]
```

but this gives me a `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for minimal values to `Series` with same size like `df`, so compare working nice, also for filtering in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) in `loc` not necessary:

```
new_df = df[df['ppm'] == df.groupby('a').ppm.transform('min')]
print (new_df)
       a  ppm
0  anno1    1
2  anno2    2
3  anno2    2
```

Comment: Thanks! This is working nicely. For anyone, who also tries to understand the `transform` function, I can recommend this: https://pbpython.com/pandas_transform.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach if you don't mind resetting the original index:

```
df.merge(df.groupby(['a'])['ppm'].min().reset_index(), how='inner')
```

Output:

```
    a   ppm
0   anno1   1
1   anno2   2
2   anno2   2
```